# Debugging an MCU short circuit

Tags: microcontroller, dac, short-circuit, troubleshooting

I have a board with an STM32F103VGT6 MCU. Yesterday, the MCU worked fine, I had just gotten semihosting working, LED blinking, played around getting a timer running and so on.

I then decided to try to see if I can get the DAC to output a voltage. I simply turned on the peripherals (GPIO port A and the DAC itself), enabled the DAC and wrote a half-scale value. Once I uploaded the program and attached the debugger, the program started running fine, but while I was reaching for my DMM to check the DAC output, I thought I might be smelling burning electronics, though apparently the smell wasn't too strong as I wasn't worried at the time. Then the MCU suddenly stopped working, i.e. it stopped outputting the timer values on the debug channel, LED stopped blinking and so on. Based on the values output, this happened 26 seconds after startup (plus a few more seconds for initialization). At this point I realized that the regulator is very hot, and disconnected power from the board.

After trying out some things (which included connecting power for a few seconds at a time, as I didn't realize what's going on), I noticed that 3.3V and GND are shorted. I have a jumper on the board which allows breaking the power between the regulator and the rest of the circuit, for measuring current, and with that I was able to verify that the short is on the MCU side. The regulator seems to be working fine.

I'm now worried that I've burned the MCU and it's shorting internally. However, I don't remember it getting hot to the touch during the event, and now if I connect power for a few seconds, it does not heat up, which makes me doubt that the short would be in the MCU. The regulator pulls about 700mA (!) through the short, I would imagine that much current passing through the MCU would cause quite noticeable heating?

Also, I don't understand how could turning on the DAC or GPIOA cause such destruction (some details on the circuit in the end on the post)?

My questions:

1. What can I do to debug this? Obviously looking for shorts in individual components is a bit difficult, since the 3.3V and GND are shorted, so measuring decoupling caps or VCC pins for example just shows that the two sides are shorted. I have measured the non-power pins of the MCU, and those do not seem to be shorted to VCC or GND.
2. If it is the MCU that's broken, what, if anything, can I do to verify that? I'd really hate to cut the pins on the chip and remove it only to find out that the short remains.
3. How could turning on the wrong devices destroy the MCU (details on the circuit in the end)? It would be even worse if I swap the MCU only to burn another one (I have exactly one spare, after which there's a week of waiting and ridiculous postage to get the part...).

Now for the promised details:

- as the board is mostly unpopulated yet, there is nothing attached to any of the pins of GPIOA, except the JTAG, which shares some of them.
- the Vref+ -pin on the MCU is unconnected except for the decoupling caps, as there is a external reference which is not yet soldered on the board. As I was just testing, I was under the impression that VCC would be used for Vref+ in this case (although I realize now this is probably not the case). Could this actually cause destruction of the part?

Finally, relevant parts of the schematic, sorry for the messy layout:
[image: GPIOA. The labels are all currently unconnected.]

Fig 1: GPIOA. All the labeled connections go to unpopulated areas of the board.

[image: Power]

Fig 2: Power. 3.3VDAC is currently unconnected, but the caps are populated.

Finally, the DAC init code:

```
//Set up DAC1
RCC->APB1ENR |= (uint32_t)0x20000000;//Weird bug in stm32f10x.h, 
                                     //the macro constant isn't defined for XL devices
RCC->APB2ENR |= RCC_APB2ENR_IOPAEN;
DAC->CR |= DAC_CR_EN1;
DAC->DHR12R1 = 2048;
```

I didn't write anything to the mode configuration registers, as it looked like they should be all zeroes anyway, and this was just a very first test to see if I can get something out of the DACs. Proper init code would come later.

Comment: Don't assume default values for registers... at least one mcu i used in the past defaulted to all 1's and writing to them was required to get 0's. I always set mine at the start of code... otherwise other fun behavior follows, like needing to restart the mcu twice before it works the expected way from power up.

Comment: Yes, I wasn't going to. I was just being lazy on the first attempt to see if it would work that easily. Configuring the modes is what I would've tried next, if the board hadn't stopped working.

Comment: If you have an idea on how the wrong mode settings could lead to the MCU burning itself out, though, I would be very interested to hear.

Comment: Depends on the rest of the circuit. Do you have 2 outputs in conflict ? I'd guess turning on the DAC output may have turned on the rest of the port pins, while all were off you have no problem.

Comment: That's what I was thinking too, but I couldn't find anything like that either in the schematic or by measuring the actual board.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering how the problem got started, I convinced myself that it is very likely I've fried the MCU, so I proceeded to remove it by cutting its legs. Indeed, this resolved the short circuit, and measuring the earthly remains of the poor device shows that its VDD and VSS -pins are indeed shorted.

Also, from the STM32F103 [Getting Started -manual, page 7](http://www2.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/6c/a3/24/49/a5/d4/4a/db/CD00164185.pdf/files/CD00164185.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00164185.pdf): "In all cases, Vref+ must be between 2.4V and VDDA". I clearly broke this requirement, as the pin was floating.

Unfortunately, I ended up destroying some of the pads on the MCU in the process (probably used too much force/too dull a knife), so I will have to start the build all over again...

Anyway, the answer is that based on circumstantial evidence, it was likely that the MCU is fried, and this indeed turned out to be correct.

**Update:**

Having built the second prototype, with the reference now included, the MCU survived turning on the DAC, and seems to be working fine. There was also a minor mistake in the code, in that the reset state of the pins is floating input, whereas the recommended setting is analog input when using the DAC. I do not believe that this is the cause for the self-destruction though, as I would imagine the datasheet would state this a bit more strongly than as a "recommendation" if ignoring it destroys the whole device. However, I'm obviously a bit reluctant to put that to the test!

Just for anyone trying to google it, let me state the conclusion: floating Vref on STM32 destroys the chip!

**Final note:** do read Spehro's comments though, which suggest that there's a chance that this was simply a coincidence involving destruction by static electricity.

Comment: The usual cause of what you describe is applying a signal with no power (then applying power) or allowing a test probe to slip with the power on. In poorly controlled conditions ESD could be a cause too (especially with power on).

Comment: @SpehroPefhany There was a slight "burning electronics" smell from the moment I turned the system on (so lasting about 30 seconds before the MCU stopped working, i.e. my heartbeat LED stopped and the SWD connection dropped), and this happened the very first time I tried turning on the DAC (which was right at the beginning of the code). It is possible that this was a coincidence, and I slipped the probe (I was trying to measure the DAC output to see if it was working), but I do not remember having any mishaps that I would've noticed.

Comment: Also, that does not explain the burning electronics smell. Also, the regulator was very hot to the touch, although as it did take me a few seconds to realize what was going on, this might have already been caused by the short.

Comment: So while what you describe is certainly possible, I'd say there's enough circumstantial evidence to suggest that this was about the floating Vref pin. I could edit the answer to say "may destroy the chip!", though, if you prefer?

Comment: That's actually the usual result- the chip latches up, overheats and melts into a short internally if the power supply is not limited to a rather low maximum current.

Comment: Hmm, ok... I guess it's impossible to know for sure without testing, and I'd be almost tempted to do so if it wouldn't take an evening and cost about 25€ in components to build enough of the board to make this happen (or not).

Comment: A hot air rework station is really worth the money - with a little practice you can remove a chip and if it turns out not to be the culprit re-install it.  And you should get at least one cycle of that without lifting pads even on a handmade PCB.  These are now down to around 60 USD here, not sure what they would cost you but they're all imported from the same corner of the world.

Comment: @ChrisStratton yeah, I've been thinking of getting one. My problem is mostly that I'll be moving away from the country I'm living in right now (Iceland) either next fall or the one following, and trying to avoid buying anything to ease the move. Further, everything here is ridiculously expensive, and when ordering from abroad the postage, customs and so on tend to amount to the same. So I'd easily end up paying double what things cost in the US. If it were otherwise, I'd probably already have a proper bench PSU, oscilloscope, hot-air rework station, hot tweezers, and so on...

Comment: Understood.  I will say the hot air should be a priority though, for the time and damage it will save - the newer design with the fan in the handpiece is fairly compact.  As are modern scopes.  A bench supply is not all that useful if you mostly do MCU circuits, and the small hot air tip will generally substitute for heated tweezers.  You can try an ordinary heat gun, but it's harder to control what you remove.

Comment: Noted. Thanks for the advice, makes sense, and the hot air being the cheapest of these I'll definitely look around for an opportunity to get one!

Answer (score 7):

Finding a short on a board can be a challenge. One technique involves injecting a fairly high current into the board and then using a micro voltmeter to profile the voltage drops across the board to zero into the key area. I've tried this several times with mixed success.

One time some 15 years ago we had done a board spin on a fairly complex board that was full of digital, telcoms, audio and video in a mixed signal design. A half dozen of the new boards were built and in initial testing we noticed injection of digital noise patterns into the audio output from the board. It became clear that someplace on the board a digital GND was shorting into the audio GND. (Note that the audio GND and digital GND had to be tied together at one point under the audio chip). Finding the improper GND connection ended up being a fruitless exercise over more than a day of investigation. In the end I determined that I needed to sacrifice one board and used a Dremel tool to grind the board surface in two places down into the digital GND plane and the audio GND plane. Two 10 AWG solid copper wires were then soldered down to the GND plane copper *(that took a lot of heat to achieve)*. I then shorted the two heavy copper wires across a fully charged 12V car battery allowing many many Amps to flow into the board. It took about 12 seconds for the short to reveal itself. A small plume of smoke rose up out of a via hole. In this case it was an improperly placed digital via that encroached on the audio GND plane pour. PCB DRC failed to flag an error because as far as it was concerned GND = GND.

The lesson learned was that it is a good idea to consider isolating two GND areas like this through some ferrite beads. Sometimes zero ohm resistor components can be used for the same thing. This makes the two GND areas separate nets on the PCB and the DRC checking can flag shorts.

Comment: The same thing can be done without a physical component in some EDA software by using ['net ties'](http://www.smtnet.com/library/files/upload/NetTies-and-How-to-Use-Them.pdf). A similar problem arises with planar coils- the two ends of the coil appear to be the same net unless you add something like a net tie.